Android sdkmanager tool was found but failed to run
I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to install Flutter on Windows 11, and currently everything looks fine Except the Android Licenses.
So I tried to run flutter doctor --android-licenses but it returns this result:
capture
I tried unistalling the Android Studio and again installed it with Downloading latest version of cmdlets package but the problem still occurs.
So what's going wrong here? Please help me with I don't really know what to do now?

have you installed Android SDK Command-line Tools ?

Please don't post terminal output as screenshot. The output is plain text so please just copy and paste it into your question and format it as code.

Set Android SDK Location in Flutter

Flutter needs to know the location of your Android SDK. You can set this manually by setting the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to the path of your Android SDK. The default path is usually C:\Users<Your-Username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

To set the environment variable:
Search for "Environment Variables" in Windows search and select "Edit the system environment variables".
In the System Properties window, click "Environment Variables".
Under "System Variables", click "New" and add ANDROID_HOME as the variable name and the path to your SDK as the variable value.

Restart your command prompt or IDE to ensure the new environment variable is recognized.


